Django: How to filter based on custom field generated in serializer to_representation
I have a custom field in my extra action view that gets added by overriding to_representation() in serializer. I want to add a filter based on that value. How can I achieve that?
views.py
class MyFiltersetclass(filters.Filterset):
  name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="exact", field_name="name")
  
  class Meta:
     model= MyModel
     fields = ["name"]

class MyViewset():
   ....
   @action(detail=True, method=["get"], queryset=MyModel.objects.filter(type=1), serilizer=MyModelSerializer, filterset_class=MyFiltersetclass)
   def action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      qs = self.get_object()
      queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

      page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
      if page:
         serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
      else:
         serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

model.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    summaries = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def summary(self):
        if not self.summaries:
            return {}

        return custom_func(self.summaries)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "model_view_1"
        managed = False

serializer.py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    summary = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        summary = data.pop("summary")

        data["field_1"] = summary.get("field_1")

        return {**data}

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ["summaries"]

Now I want to add a filter that could filter based on field_1 just like how we have added filter for name in filterset class.
